# Filter second dropdown using first

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

insert.php

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<?php
        include 'config.php';
    ?>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0-beta1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function catFilter(val){

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"filterDropDown.php",
                data: 'cat='+val,
                success: function(data){
                    $("#prd_cat").html(data);
                }
            })
        }
    </script>
    <body>


    <table>
        <form id="product" method="POST" enctype = "multipart/form-data" novalidate>
            <table align="center" width="750" border ="2">
                <tr align="center">
                    <td colspan="7"><h2>Insert Product</h2></td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Type of Product: </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="prd_type" onChange="catFilter(this.value)">
                            <option value="">Select Type</option>
                            <?php
                                $run = mysqli_query($con, "Select * from typeproduct");
                                while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run)){
                                    $type_title = $row['type_title'];
                                    $type_id = $row['id'];
                                    echo "<option value='$type_id'>$type_title</option>";
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>

                    </td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>Select Category: </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="prd_cat">
                            <option value="">Select Category</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Select Sub Category: </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="prd_sub_cat">
                            <option value="">Select Sub Category</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Select Brand: </td>
                    <td>
                        <select id="prd_brand">
                            <option value="">Select Brand</option>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td><button value="Insert Product" name="insertPrd">Insert Product</button></td>
                </tr>
        </form>
        </form>
        </form>
    </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

filterDropDown.php

```
<?php
include 'config.php';


    ?>

    <option>Select Category</option>
    <?php
    $get_cat = "Select * from categories where type_id = '"._POST['cat']"'";
    $run_cat = mysqli_query($con, $get_cat);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($run_cat)){

    ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['cat_id'];?>"><?php echo $row['cat_name'];?></option>
    <?php   
    }
    ?>

    <?php

?>
```

I am trying to create a multilevel dropdown list to insert products and filter it using different categories. config.php connects to the database. I want to filter the categories using type_id.

But I think there is some problem in my ajax code as it is not able to redirect to filterDropDown.php as I checked by an alert statement in filterDropDown.php.

Comment: try `data: {cat: val},`

Comment: Sorry... Didn't work.